# Django Rest Framework - How to get field of foreign key of a foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Assume I have these models:

```
ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field_a = models.IntegerField()

ModelB(models.Model):
    some_field_b = models.IntegerField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

ModelC(models.Model):
    some_field_c = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

Then in my serializer for ModelC, I have this to access the field *some_field_b* from ModelB:

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_b = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        source='some_field_b',
        slug_field='some_field_b')

    field_a = ???

    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = ('some_field_c', 'field_b', 'field_a')
```

But what should I add to *field_a* to retrieve the value of *some_field_a*, in the same way I'm retrieving the value from *some_field_b*?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand your example, but it seems you wish to walk the relation from C -> B -> A and get that value. You can follow the relation in the `source` argument using dot syntax, much like you would if you were accessing the object directly.

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_b = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        source='b.some_field_b',
        slug_field='some_field_b')

    field_a = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        source='b.a.some_field_a',
        slug_field='some_field_a')

    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = ('some_field_c', 'field_b', 'field_a')
```

Comment: Awesome, I was trying using `b__a` notation, which wasn't working. Here's the relevant doc section: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source